# How can I turn on fast running on the Smart Moving mod for Survival mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have the [Smart Moving](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/smart-moving-1-12-2) mod installed in my modpack for 1.12.2, which has a speed changer that can be activated by tapping the keys <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd>, but it seems I can only use it in creative mode. Does anyone know how to make this possible in Survival mode too, and not just creative? Also, to prevent cheating, is there a way to make this only possible for certain users as well? Also, I'm not using a server for this, if anyone is wondering.